# Check if part of text matches a regex

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to build a component similar to Google Play's credit card adding:

[image: demo]

Where the user starts typing the credit card number, and only the credit card images that stay visible, are of the cards that matches part of the credit card number pattern.

For example:

Looking at MasterCard regex: ^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$

If the user type "5", "53", "531", the image of master card should be visible.

I guess it can be done with Pattern and Matcher class, but how?

Using `match()` method is not good, as it trying to match against all the pattern.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `^5([1-5][0-9]{0,14})?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a pattern for live validation, you can use

```
^5([1-5][0-9]{0,14})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV4tH1/1).

Note you cannot use it for *final* string validation, you will have to use your current regex for it.

The main thing about a regex for live input validation is that it allows the next character only if the previous one matches, and that is possible with nested optional groups. Since you have only 3 parts: 1) the first obligatory `5`, then `1` to `5` digit, and then any 0 to 14 digits, you may use just one optional group around `[1-5][0-9]{0,14}` pattern and and make sure you allow zero or up to 14 other digits.

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `5` - obligatory `5`
- `([1-5][0-9]{0,14})?` - an optional sequence (1 or 0 occurrences) of:

  - `[1-5]` - a digit from `1` to `5`
  - `[0-9]{0,14}` - any zero to forteen digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Use your pattern for activation the button
and this for the image

```
 ^5[1-5][0-9]{0, 14}$
```

Comment: This `^5[1-5][0-9]{0, 14}$` will not allow `5` because `[1-5]` is obligatory. It also has a malformed limiting (bound/range) quantifier.